# YUI compressor 2.4.7 can't compress js files

Tags: java, javascript, yui-compressor

I used this command:

```
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar -o '.js$:-min.js' *.js
```

and I got 0KB file named `'.js$` on windows 7

why?

what should I do to compress batch js files?

Comment: it's a new syntax since yuicompressor v2.4.6 to process multiple files

Comment: @zerkms According to the [YUICompressor README](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor) on GitHub, it's an "output pattern": `java -jar yuicompressor.jar -o '.css$:-min.css' *.css` is an example pattern for minifying all CSS files into equivalently named files that end with `-min.css`.

Comment: @yahz Do you get similar output using double quotes? And if you escape the `:` and/or `$`?

Comment: @apsillers yes, I got .js$ with double quotes

Comment: @apsillers escape `:` and/or `$` and  it throws `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Answer (score 1):

The following command worked for me (on Win7 without any quote), but I have no idea why.

```
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar -o .js$:-min.js *.js
```

It would be really appreciated if anybody could share some insight.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I've created a simple batch file (name it as `test.bat`) with the following contents trying to figure out what actually happens.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (%*) do (
echo %%a
)
```

When I run it with `test.bat -o '.js$:-min.js' *s`, it gave out something like this:

```
-o
'.js$:-min.js'
fb.js
test.cs
test.js
```

So I think the command prompt doesn't process the quotation marks in the way of *nix.